# Greenplum add multiple partitions by range to existing table

Tags: sql, database-partitioning, greenplum

can't wrap my mind around adding partitions to the existing partitioned table in Pivotal Greenplum via this [documentation](https://docs.greenplum.org/6-1/ref_guide/sql_commands/ALTER_TABLE.html)

```
create table tab_name
(
    day_dt date,
    id text,
    s_id text,
    type text,
    amt numeric(19,4)
)
distributed randomly
partition by range (day_dt)
    (
    start (date '2020-09-18') inclusive
    end (date '2020-10-02') exclusive
    every (interval '1 day')
    );
```

This is DDL.
I need to add new partitions to every new day since 2020-10-02 before adding data to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name ADD PARTITION
             START (date '2020-10-02') INCLUSIVE
             END (date '2020-11-01') EXCLUSIVE;
```

But this one would create only one partition, and I need on every day.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION` command variation, which allows the recursive addition of multiple partitions. I understand you can only add one partition at the time, at the "edges" of the existing partitioning pattern.

Some thoughts on how you can achieve what you describe, include:

- issuing multiple `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION` statements (potentially wrapped inside a function which would allow you to do recursive actions)
- adding a default partition for all dates not in the (2020-09-18, 2020-10-02) range, before adding/exchanging/splitting the new partitions

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic function that takes `datestart text,dateend text,table_schema text,table_name text` as parameter and loops over to add a partition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partitionfunction(datestart text,dateend text,table_schema text,table_name text)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
    
declare
var_Table_schema text;
var_Table_name text;
var_dateStart date;
var_dateEnd date;
var_endPartition date;
BEGIN
var_Table_schema := Table_schema;
var_Table_name := Table_name;
var_dateStart := to_date(dateStart,'YYYY-MM-DD');
var_dateEnd := to_date(dateEnd,'YYYY-MM-DD');
WHILE var_dateStart < var_dateEnd
loop
var_endPartition = var_dateStart + interval '1 DAY'; --You can also change it for weeks or days
execute ' alter table '|| Table_schema ||'.'|| Table_name || '
add partition start('''||var_dateStart||''') end(
'''||var_endPartition||''')';
var_dateStart = var_dateStart + interval '1 DAY'; --You can also change it for weeks or days
END loop;
end;

$$
EXECUTE ON ANY;
```